# copy activity is not exporting complete data in orc

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am newbie Azure data factory, I am trying to export the data from azure sql to azure blob in an orc file using copy activity. I am exporting 100 tables in orc files using Azure data factory, But a few of the tables are not getting exported completely in ORC files. When I checked in azure table there are 2 millions row, but orc file of the tables only has 10k records. Can anyone help me how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you using a query or table name as source? Do these tables (that don't fully sync) have anything in common? perhaps you should share more information about your pipeline and datasets, with screenshots so we can try to see what might be causing this behavior.

Comment: Hi@cloud_anny I have tried dynamic approach with relationship between the tables. have you tried dynamic approach from Azure sql to blob as Orc?